# Selecting from double value options

Tags: web-app, user-expectation, selection, grid, multi-selection

In a complex issue, I have a grid of items that user should select two values from a list of pair values.

[image: Grid of items]
In above example, you can see that user for `Item 1` selects `[ 65 - 36 ]` pair value set and puts one value for `[ Very High ]` column and another one for `[ High ]` column, that being them close together are not important.
And for `Item 2` selects `[ 100 - 0 ]` pair value and puts just `100` for `[ Average ]` column because of pair value has a `0`.

In my current UI, I use just some combo-boxes in each cell those at first have a list of values like `[0, 20, 35, 50, 65, 80, 100]` then after selecting one of them by user (i.e. 35) I only show other one (i.e. 65) for other cells of its row (i.e. row of `item 1`) and in its own cell I show a list of with its value and `0` -to rollback current changes- (i.e. 0, 35).

My users tell it's hard to use and to understand, but I can't find a better way!, Can you please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end it up with this solution, Hope to help someone else:

I add a Combo-Box for combinations - pair values - in each row of grid.
So, at first, user will see a message about "selecting a combination at first".
Then after browsing Combo-Box and select one of them, the message will disappear.
Now user will see a Combo-Box in each cell with values of the combination:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the exact content, your user has to follow these steps:

1. Select an element for each row
2. Select 2 columns in that row for that element

In this case I think it is really useful to separate both steps and not to mix them in the same step. Because if the user wants to change his mind and select previously selected element for a row he has to go back change that row to a none value.

So, in your case and following a two step setup:

```
Step1:
            Very High       High        Average     Low     Very Low
_____________________________________________________________________
50-50
65-35
80-20
100-0


Step2:
            Item1       Item2       Item3       Item4
______________________________________________________
50-50
65-35
80-20
100-0
```

Or the other way round. The idea is that each step is done and once done then the user can proceed to the next step. If the user wanted to change step1 then he would loose changes made in step2.

Comment: Tnx, But user doesn't need to go back change a row to a none value, when user select two values, he will see `0` above his/her selected value, If user wants to change place of one value he/she changes only that value to `0` then select it from other cells or row ;).